# How to concatenate two files (removing the first line of the second file) in a single line of unix command?

Tags: file, unix, sed, merge

I am trying to create a new file (say `file3`) by stacking two files (`file1` and `file2`) together. I need the entirety of `file1` but want to exclude the first row of `file2`. What I have now is a two step process using `head` and `sed`.

```
cat file1.csv file2.csv > file3.csv
sed -i 1001d file3.csv
```

The last step requires me to find out the length of `file1` before removing the line after so that it corresponds to the first line of `file2`. How do I combine these two lines into a single line of code? I tried this and it failed:

```
cat file1.csv sed 1d file2.csv > file3.csv
```

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a compound statement like this:

```
{ cat file1.csv; sed '1d' file2.csv; } > file3.csv
```

Comment: This works. Thank you! What is the logic of the code within the braces?

Comment: The first statement prints the contents of `file1.csv` and the second statement prints the contents of `file2.csv` but deleting/ignoring the first line because of `1d`. The combined output of the two statements is then written to `file3.csv`. Just like you asked for really ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use process substitution, like:

```
cat file1.csv <(tail -n +2 file2.csv) > file3.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is `cat file1.csv > file3.csv; tail -n +2 file2.csv >> file3.csv`.

Another one is `tail -n +2 file2.csv | cat file1.csv - > file3.csv`

Answer (score 0):

You can use your second try, but with process substitution:

```
cat file1.csv <(sed '1d' file2.csv) > file3.csv
```

Your command failed because `sed` was treated as filename that `cat` tried to access.

If your shell doesn't support process substitution, you can use this instead:

```
sed '1d' file2.csv | cat file1.csv - > file3.csv
```

Alternatively, you can use awk:

```
awk 'FNR!=NR && FNR==1 {next} 1' file{1,2}.csv > file3.csv
```

`FNR!=NR` is true if we're not in the first file (file record number is not equal to overall record number), and `FNR==1` is true on the first line of each file. Together, the condition is true on the first line of each but the first file; `next` skips that line. `1` gets all other lines printed.

Comment: I tried your first option and other variations of it and got the following error :

`sh.exe": cannot make pipe for process substitution: Function not implemented`

Comment: It looks like your shell doesn't support process substitution. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I am using git bash

Comment: You should edit your question to include which shell you are using